# Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp, evm

I don't know where i'm doing mistake. I have deployed my contract through remix and truffle and it was deployed without any mistake but now i'm deploying it from web3 solc@0.4.24 version and EVM is reverting my transaction.

Here's my code.

```
    let privateKey = req.body.from_private_key;
    let fromAddress = req.body.from_address;
    let _startTime = req.body.startTime;
    let _endTime = req.body.endTime;
    let _goal = req.body.goal;
    let _wallet = req.body.wallet;

    _goal = web3.utils.toWei(_goal, 'ether');
    web3.eth.defaultAccount = fromAddress;

    let count = await                                                                           web3.eth.getTransactionCount(web3.eth.defaultAccount);

    let gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
    let gasLimit = 3000000;

    const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface));

    const deployData = result.deploy({
      data: bytecode,
      arguments: [_startTime, _endTime, _goal.toString(), _wallet]
    }).encodeABI();

    let tx = {
      from: fromAddress,
      nonce: web3.utils.toHex(count),
      gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(gasPrice),
      gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(gasLimit),
      data: deployData,
      chainId: 0x04
    };

      web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, privateKey).then(signed => {
      web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction).on('receipt', console.log)
    });
```

Compiling from here:

```
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc')
const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname,'contracts','MyContract.sol')
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath,'utf8');/
console.log(solc.compile(source.toString(),1));
module.exports = 
solc.compile(source.toString(),1).contracts[':MyContract']
```

And Response is :

> (node:22390) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
>   {
>     "blockHash": "0xb6cbb03fcf1ea74b6dfa09d8fef7ed28fb3ec176a5b174de2d40ebabf1825965",
>     "blockNumber": 4375769,
>     "contractAddress": "0x33301cc2B245528D5F5720594148F16b05De1910",
>     "cumulativeGasUsed": 3000000,
>     "from": "0x57a9ce9d1e4834d43507ba77cb9d30f7dd0da307",
>     "gasUsed": 3000000,
>     "logs": [],
>     "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
>     "status": false,
>     "to": null,
>     "transactionHash": "0xa99d769d4965738eba5ebc33ccaf52c5b171bd66f758072bec55b7260932161c",
>     "transactionIndex": 0
>   }
>   (node:22390) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace in your transaction https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0xa99d769d4965738eba5ebc33ccaf52c5b171bd66f758072bec55b7260932161c

```
Step    PC      Operation     Gas            GasCost    Depth
[1]     0       DUP1          2721080        0          1
```

Its seems the beginning of your bytecode is wrong.

```
0x806040526000600455600580...
```

Comment: Here is my deployed contract on rinkeby which is deployed through remix.
i don't how starting of my bytecode is going wrong here in web3.
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x6211058c931a8be30d0c8991c7d0d17ab5500557#code

Comment: @HamzaYasin How do you create bytecode? The contract at the address you point starts with `0x6080604052600060045560006005`.

Comment: I'm creating it through solc@0.4.24

Comment: @HamzaYasin How do you create contract bytecode? From commandline (which command), from a script (which scripts)? If you execute `console.log(bytecode)` before deploy what does it looks like? Did you try first deploying a "hello world" contract to ensure your script is working? Either your bytecode is erroneouly generated or in another part of your script it cuts the beginning.

Comment: Please see above i have updated my question with my compiling scrypt.
Another thing i have my contract is in flat file of solidity, it was consisting of 6, 7 contract files and i made it a single flat file to compile and deploy from here.

Comment: Thanks, I sought out this issue by applying 0x prefix in start of data bytecode.